# SQL Server data migration to a clone database but with different collation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I initially wanted to change the collation of all the columns in the database but ran into many problems so I was suggested to create a new database with the new collation and migrate the data from the old one.
How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

From SSMS >> Database >> {DB} >> Tasks >> Generate Scripts.  (Remember to include data)